# Bayesian ranking

Tags: postgresql, order-by

I have the following table in my database:

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║  Name  ║ total_stars ║ total_reviews ║
╠════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ Item A ║          27 ║             7 ║
║ Item B ║          36 ║             9 ║
║ Item C ║          27 ║             7 ║
║ Item D ║          30 ║             6 ║
║ Item E ║           0 ║             0 ║
║ Item F ║           0 ║             0 ║
║ Item F ║          15 ║             3 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

I was looking at [this article](http://www.andymoore.ca/2010/02/bayesian-ratings-your-salvation-for-user-generated-content/) and trying to implement Bayesian rankings in PostgreSQL database.

The formula given for the rank is

```
br = ( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) / 
(avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)
```

where:

- avg_num_votes: The average number of votes of all items that have num_votes>0
- avg_rating: The average rating of each item (again, of those that have num_votes>0)
- this_num_votes: number of votes for this item
- this_rating: the rating of this item

This is the query I came up with, but it is not working:

```
with avg_num_votes as (
      select AVG(total_reviews) 
           from business 
           where total_reviews != 0), 
       avg_rating as (
          select AVG(total_stars/total_reviews) 
          from business 
          where total_reviews != 0)
select * from business 
  order by ((avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (total_stars)) / (avg_num_votes + total_reviews);
```

I am getting:

```
ERROR:  column "avg_num_votes" does not exist
```

Comment: Your CTE Appears to have the same name as a column.

Comment: +1 for having ASCII art in the post! +1 to Stackexchange for supporting it too!

Comment: While ASCII art is really nice, it would be more practical to have a `CREATE TABLE` statement or a link to a demo on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
with avg_num_votes as (
      select AVG(total_reviews) 
           from business 
           where total_reviews != 0),
```

`avg_num_votes` is the name of the *table*.  The column itself gets a nice auto-generated name (in this case, most probably `avg`), which is clearly not what you want and refer below.  You can give a name to the column two ways:

```
with avg_num_votes as (
      select AVG(total_reviews) AS avg_num_votes
      ...
```

or

```
with avg_num_votes(avg_num_votes) as (
      select AVG(total_reviews) 
      ...
```

Choose whch one you prefer.  The two only differ in readability.

**But** this is only a part of the problem.  In the main query you have to refer the CTEs constructed with `WITH`.  In order to get meaningful results, you have to join then on a column present in all tables - so, if you choose `Name`, then you have to do something like

```
with avg_num_votes(avg_num_votes) as (
      select AVG(total_reviews), Name
      from ...
      GROUP BY Name
      ...
select b.* 
from business b
    JOIN avg_num_votes v ON b.Name = v.Name
    JOIN avg_rating r ON b.Name = r.Name
...
```